# jQuery Magnific Popup is not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, magnific-popup

I have an issue with the jQuery Magnific Popup plugin, I did what I read in the documentation but it doesn't work, when I click on the link the image don't open in a popup. And I have no errors.

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="{{case.image}}" title="{{case.description}}">
    <img ng-src="{{case.image}}">
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.thumbnail').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image', 
            delegate: 'a'
        });
        console.log('ok'); 
    });
</script>
```

I'm so sorry if it's a newbie mistake, but I looked everywhere and I don't see what's wrong, nothing wrong in the console ... Maybe there is a problem with AngularJs, but I am not an expert ...

Thank you a lot for your help.

I hosted my app to help you see what's wrong : http://azilizblanchet.fr/CameleonCatalogue/#/services

Comment: _"Doesn't work"_? What's going wrong? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: When I click on the link, the image opens in a new page and there is no error.

Comment: The docs say to use a div containing anchors rather than an anchor containing images.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean (sorry I'm not English-native). You think to problem comes from my HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

Magnific popup requires the href attribute on the element. Just add it to the image tag and it should work.

```
<img ng-src="{{case.image}}" href="{{case.image}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove delegate option.

Just:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.thumbnail').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image'
        });
        console.log('ok'); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That is not working either. Maybe it's because I'm using AngularJS on these elements ? (I'm very new to AngularJS)

Comment: I don't use AngularJS, but Magnific Popup use jQuery and Zepto. Why not to use both jQuery and AngularJS.

Comment: Both library are included in my HTML, so my jQuery code is supposed to work ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/quark2014/2357s2tv/3/ I have changed img attribute from ng-src to only src.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I hosted my app, maybe it could help you see what's wrong : http://azilizblanchet.fr/CameleonCatalogue/#/services

Comment: Can you include all resources (JS, images, etc..) correctly? Some gets code 404. I think that problem is that the content isn't completely loaded when you initialize Magnific Popup plugin. The container-fluid could be still empty. Wait until the content of the container-fluid is completely loaded then run your JS as before.